# How to connect aws vpc and gcp bigquery with vpn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, vpc

I want to connect aws vpc and bigquery in gcp using aws transit gateway.
I would like to know how to connect using gcp's Private Google Access.
If there is another way, please let me know.
thank you.

I created Private Google Access, but how do I connect it with bigquery?

Comment: BigQuery is a public service. Are you hoping to route BigQuery reqeusts from within AWS VPC over a VPN tunnel to a Google Cloud VPC and proxy those requests to BigQuery from there? You may be better off creating some form of query API server inside the Google Cloud VPC that can talk privately to BigQuery and then have clients from the AWS VPC make requests to that API over the VPN tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

As @jarmod mentioned in comments,

You may be better off creating some form of query API server inside the `Google Cloud VPC` that can talk privately to `BigQuery` and then have clients from the `AWS VPC` make requests to that API over the VPN tunnel.

As of now, this is the best practice.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.